# How to export the complex report to PDF or Excel

Tags: java, excel, pdf, report

I have more than a dozen different template reports, including many tables, column -shaped or fan -shaped, whether there are some tools or jars that can be exported easily. I need to use Java to achieve it.

The data will be prepared. no need java code to handle

Comment: Great! What did you've tried so far and what problem do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.